# Why does stat return wrong result?

Tags: c, stat

I want to check whether given arguments are directory or not by using `stat`. The program takes 2 argument: when first arguments is not directory or it does not exist code works correctly.

But when first argument is a directory and exists, and the second argument does not exist, the program says both of them exist -- wrong result. I would like to know why it does not work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int main(int n, char **argv)
{
    char *dir_1=argv[1], *dir_2=argv[2];


    if (is_dir(dir_1) == 0)
            printf("Directory %s exists.\n", dir_1);
    else
            printf("Directory %s does not exist.\n", dir_1);

    if (is_dir(dir_2) == 0)
            printf("Directory  %s exists.\n", dir_2);
    else
            printf("Directory  %s does not exist.\n", dir_2);

}


int is_dir(char *file)
{
        struct stat file_stat;
        stat(file, &file_stat);
        return( (S_ISDIR(file_stat.st_mode)) ? 0 : -1);
}
```

Comment: Because before using function's *expected* output, you should check it's return value and see if it worked at all.

Comment: If the function is called only once, then it always works correctly. But when I call it twice, then it does not return the expected value in all cases.

Comment: You don't have a function prototype for `is_dir` so the compiler assumes you are passing an `int` parameter. Perhaps that is why it misbehaves. Enable and take note of all compiler warnings.

Comment: Check the return result along with `errno`. It will give you a clue.

Comment: I added function prototype, but still get the same results. It does not misbehave always. If I call it only once then it always works correctly. But if I call it twice: `dir_1` is a directory which exists, and `dir_2` does not exist, then the code says both of them exist.

Comment: And you don't even check `argc` (which you call `n`) which is *essential* to prevent "finger trouble" where you imagine the program does not work due to lack of input. Lots of non-checking - when *robust* code should check everything in sight. Your comment about calling it once or twice - is that because you entered one or two arguments? The program calls it twice.

Comment: file_stat is left undefined if stat() encounters an error (like ENOENT), so it contains garbage.

Comment: Your code doesn't test if dir_2 exists, it is just testing some bit pattern in undefined value.

Comment: [stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) should return 0, only when it was successful. In my case `dir_2` does not exists, which means `stat` cannot be successful. If there is any error, then `stat` should not return 0.

Comment: But presented code discards stat's return value anyway.

Comment: I know my code does not check if dir_2 exists, but if it does not exist then `stat` needs to return -1. And if `dir_1` does not exist, `is_dir` does not return 0. Everything works correctly, if `is_dir` called only once.

Comment: But stat doesn't fill struct stat on failure at all, you're returning garbage expression then. Stat is not required to fill struct with zeros or anything on error, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file does not exist, `stat` itself returns `-1`, and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`. But since the first directory existed and was a directory, the `struct stat` was filled with the information of a directory; this happens to be located at the exact same location in the stack for the second `stat` invocation. The second `stat` failed with the `errno` `ENOENT`, but then `is_dir` interpreted the values left by the first invocation.

---

More correct implementation for the `is_dir` could be:

```
int is_dir(char *file)
{
    struct stat file_stat;

    // if an error occurs, we return 0 for false
    if (stat(file, &file_stat) < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // otherwise we return whatever the S_ISDIR returns
    return S_ISDIR(file_stat.st_mode);
}
```

Notice that I change the return value too; a function such as `is_dir` is expected to return a boolean value that is truish (non-zero) in the case of the function name stating a true fact, zero otherwise.

You'd use it like:

```
if (is_dir(dir_1)) {
        printf("Directory %s exists.\n", dir_1);
}
else {
        printf("Directory %s does not exist.\n", dir_1);
}

if (is_dir(dir_2)) {
        printf("Directory  %s exists.\n", dir_2);
}
else {
        printf("Directory  %s does not exist.\n", dir_2);
}
```

---

Note that the return value 0 in this case does not mean that there necessarily is no directory with that name; the `stat` system call could fail also because of insufficient permissions and so on; extending the logic (interpreting the value of `errno`) is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Or, to be clib-like, it may be renamed to test_dir.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I just wanted to know why it returned 0 when second directory did not exist. I thought `struct stat` was initialised to some value.

Comment: For what it's worth, the original program worked as expected for me.  Of course, that's always one possible outcome of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is after another was accepted. `S_ISDIR` does not exist in MSVC, instead there is `_S_IFDIR`. After replacing that the compiler informs that `is_dir()` does not return a value. The reason being, `_S_IFDIR` is a mask, not a function. So after a few tweaks to the code, I get this which works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int is_dir(char *file)
{
    struct stat file_stat;
    if (stat(file, &file_stat) == 0)                    // check it worked
        return file_stat.st_mode & _S_IFDIR;            // it's a status mask
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)                         // conventional ids
{
    char *dir_1, *dir_2;
    if (argc < 3) return 0;                             // check silliness
    dir_1=argv[1];
    dir_2=argv[2];

    if (is_dir(dir_1))                                  // reversed the logic
        printf("%s is a Directory.\n", dir_1);
    else
        printf("%s is not a Directory.\n", dir_1);      // better text

    if (is_dir(dir_2))
        printf("%s is a Directory.\n", dir_2);
    else
        printf("%s is not a Directory.\n", dir_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
>test test.c wtest
test.c is not a Directory.
wtest is a Directory.
```

And the other way round:

```
>test wtest test.c
wtest is a Directory.
test.c is not a Directory.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a small part of a project which needs to be cross platform. So `_S_IFDIR` will be useful.